# What are the strengths + weaknesses of Surgically Masking over CPAP devices' air inlet?

Tags: cpap

[image]

Many patients go the extra mile/**mask**! See picture above. In addition to the CPAP filter that they use and replace regularly,  they mask over their CPAP machine's air intake, with a Surgical Mask that they replace regularly. They have "gone the extra mask" like this for years, without incident, for 2 reasons. For instance, ["the DreamPort interface could be used with an N95 mask."](https://www.thecpapshop.com/blog/bleep-creates-n95-conversion-kit-to-treat-covid-19/)

1. Some need to save money by replacing CPAP filters less, without [adverse effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverse_effect). They reckon that as a first layer of defence, a surgical mask shall lessen the amount of particulates to be filtered by the CPAP filter, therefore lengthen each CPAP filter's lifespan.
2. The official replacement filters don't filter antigens, particularly allergens, as effectively as surgical masks.

### What are the reasons FOR + AGAINST "going the extra surgical mask" like this?

On February 18 2022, Alberta Health Services required ["fit-tested N95 respirator
(mask) when BPAP [Bi-Level Positive Airway Pressure] is in use and other AGMPs [aerosol-generating medical procedures] are performed"](https://www.albertahealthservices.ca/assets/info/ppih/if-ppih-covid-19-cc-cpap-bpap-during-covid-19-pandemic-response-maintaining.pdf).

Comment: Nice photoshop. As a new user, please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information about what we do here at the Medical Sciences Stack. I don't see anything inherently wrong with it other than you would need to create a tight seal around the inlet to actually filter anything. It could also be a concern with air intake flow rate, but I don't know enough about the rates needed and strength of the pumps in there to do an authoritative answer.

Comment: What are your sources for the claims you make in #1 and #2? Questions here are required to demonstrate some degree of prior research, so citing your sources for your claims of fact would be a good way to do that.

Comment: @CareyGregory research added.